# With git, how can I perform a git add and still have it ignore the patterns in .gitignore?

Tags: git

I want to do something like `git add *.java` and not let it throw up just because one of those files matched the .gitignore.

For example:
In my directory I have

```
ignored.java
something.java
somethingelse.java 
somethingevenmoreelse.java.
```

where the three last files were just created by me. I then want to do `git add *.java`

and have it add those three files. In other words, instead of giving me

```
The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
ignored.java
Use -f if you really want to add them.
fatal: no files added
```

... I would rather it would just ignore the .gitignored files and add the rest.

Comment: Use zsh and discover the true power of tab completion!

Comment: In zsh, if you type `git add s*.java` and press tab, it will autocomplete to the three .java files starting with `s`. Also if you just type `git add ` and press tab, it will complete only unstaged files.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you quote the glob pattern then it will interpreted by git instead of the shell and it will ignore the ignored files before adding the rest without error.

```
git add '*.java'
```

alternatively:

```
git add \*.java
```

Comment: This is definitely the right way to go. Git will interpret glob patterns in filename args, and it will apply the gitignore patterns as appropriate without throwing an error. The error that was being thrown is because you were explicitly passing an ignored file to `git add` and it thought you must have done something you didn't mean to.